# ¿Como ver los campos de una tabla de una base de datos con sus llaves primarias y foráneas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Resulta que necesito saber como obtener todos los campos(columnas para que no me malentiendan) de una tabla de una base de datos con sus respectivas llaves foráneas y primarias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocupa esto es facil

```
select *
    FROM Information_Schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME ='Nombre de tu tabla'
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], para que de este modo consideres agregar una explicación y así entender como esto soluciona el problema

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes una forma de hacerlo, mediante los metadatos de SQL Server.

La lista de columnas de una tabla y sus propiedades:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM SYS.COLUMNS A
INNER JOIN SYS.OBJECTS B ON A.OBJECT_ID = B.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE B.TYPE='U' AND B.NAME = 'TuTabla'
```

La lista de claves primarias y foráneas:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.Constraint_name
WHERE tc.TABLE_NAME = 'TuTabla' and tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE in ('PRIMARY KEY', 'FOREIGN KEY')
```